# Best way to do JavaScript script options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script I am creating has options that the users can set, and a lot of them. I was looking for the most effective way to have the user set them. Below is how I am doing it now.

Thanks for the input and advice everyone!

```
    <!-- CFS Options Start -->
    <script>
        // Global
        var cfs_responsive="true";
        var cfs_minwidth="";
        var cfs_arrows_onlyonresponsive="true";
        var cfs_disable_lowerContent="false";
        // Primary Category
        var cfs_pc_head="true";
        var cfs_pc_head_color="#b1b6b9";
        var cfs_pc_active_head_color="#717a80";
        var cfs_pc_head_size="23px";
        var cfs_pc_arrows_color="#c1ced7";
        var cfs_pc_arrows_hover_color="#dde4e9";
        var cfs_pc_border_size="5px";
        var cfs_pc_active_border_size="5px";
        var cfs_pc_border_style="dashed";
        var cfs_pc_active_border_style="dotted";
        var cfs_pc_border_radius="0px";
        var cfs_pc_active_border_radius="0px";
        var cfs_pc_border_color="#cbd1d5";
        var cfs_pc_active_border_color="#a1acb3";
        var cfs_pc_background_color="#dde4e9";
        var cfs_pc_active_background_color="#c1ced7";
        var cfs_pc_size="183px";
        // Sub Category
        var cfs_sc_head="true";
        var cfs_sc_head_color="#b1b6b9";
        var cfs_sc_active_head_color="#717a80";
        var cfs_sc_head_size="23px";
        var cfs_sc_arrows_color="#c1ced7";
        var cfs_sc_arrows_hover_color="#dde4e9";
        var cfs_sc_border_size="5px";
        var cfs_sc_active_border_size="5px";
        var cfs_sc_border_style="dashed";
        var cfs_sc_active_border_style="dashed";
        var cfs_sc_border_radius="0px";
        var cfs_sc_active_border_radius="0px";
        var cfs_sc_border_color="#cbd1d5";
        var cfs_sc_active_border_color="#a1acb3";
        var cfs_sc_background_color="#dde4e9";
        var cfs_sc_active_background_color="#c1ced7";
        var cfs_sc_size="183px";
        // Lower Content
        var cfs_lc_toparrow="false";
        var cfs_lc_responsive_toparrow="false";
        var cfs_lc_toparrow_color="#000";
        var cfs_lc_head_size="29px";
        var cfs_lc_head_color="#717a80";
        var cfs_lc_content_size="";
        var cfs_lc_content_color="#9da3a6";
        var cfs_lc_pad_top="";
        var cfs_lowerContent_background="none";
        var cfs_lowerContent_background_border_radius="0px";
        var cfs_lowerContent_background_border_size="0px";
        var cfs_lowerContent_background_border_color="";
        var cfs_lowerContent_content_align="center";
    </script>
    <!-- CFS Options End -->
```

Comment: Create an object with all those parameters as key/value pairs.

Comment: "most effective way" --- "effectiveness" is a buzz word. There is no abstract effectiveness.

Comment: Looks like you want to create an object instead

Comment: You might want to read up on using namespaces and objects - it makes javascript behave a little more OO-like and can help with scalability down the road. If you're looking for a book I highly recommend Javascript: The Good Parts which you can find here http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective way would be to create an object like this:

```
var cfs = {
    responsive:"true",
    minwidth:"",
    arrows_onlyonresponsive:"true",
    disable_lowerContent:"false",
    pc:{
        head:"true",
        head_color:"#b1b6b9",
        active_head_color:"#717a80",
        // etc
    },
    sc:{
        head:"true",
        head_color:"#b1b6b9",
        active_head_color:"#717a80",
        // etc
    }
}
```

You can then access the properties similarly as you would the old way:

```
console.log(cfs.responsive);    // 'true'
console.log(cfs.pc.head);       // 'true'
console.log(cfs.sc.head_color); // '#b1b6b9'
```

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem :-) Also, have a look at __[this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects)__ to learn more about how objects work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
var cfs = {
    'responsive' : true,
    'minwidth' : '',
    //..
    //primary catg
    'pc' : {
        'head' : {
            'value' : true,
            'color' : "#b1b6b9",
            //..
        },
        //..
    },
    //second catg.
    'sc' : {
        'head' : {
            'value' : true,
            'color' : "#b1b6b9",
            //..
        },
        //..
    }, };
```